# Docker-compose build failed Service 'web' failed to build

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, python-poetry

I'm new to docker and deployment using docker with dockerfile and docker-composefiles.
Iam using flask and MySQL for this module.
while trying to build a web image using docker it fails. I don't know what's the issue,
Any help would be appreciated

> Project Structure
> [image: ![projectstructure]

> Docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"
    
    x-user-module: &app-container
      build:
        context: "../"
        dockerfile: "./deploy/dockerfile"
        target: development
      restart: always
    
    services:
      web:
        <<: *app-container
        links:
          - mysql
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        environment:
          - HOST
        command: >
          sh -c "uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini"
    
    
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.31
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST
      - MYSQL_DB
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER

    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

> Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
    # Uses multi-stage builds requiring Docker 17.05 or higher
    # See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
    
    # Creating a python base with shared environment variables
    FROM python:3.10-slim as python-base
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
        PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
        PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
        PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
        PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
        POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
        POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
        POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
        PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
        VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"
    
    ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"
    
    
    # builder-base is used to build dependencies
    FROM python-base as builder-base
    RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
            curl \
            build-essential
    
    # Install Poetry - respects $POETRY_VERSION & $POETRY_HOME
    ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.2.2
    RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python
    
    # We copy our Python requirements here to cache them
    # and install only runtime deps using poetry
    WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
    COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml ./
    RUN poetry install --no-dev  # respects
    
    # 'development' stage installs all dev deps and can be used to develop code.
    # For example using docker-compose to mount local volume under /app
    FROM python-base as development
    
    # Copying poetry and venv into image
    COPY --from=builder-base $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
    COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH
    
    # venv already has runtime deps installed we get a quicker install
    WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
    RUN poetry install
    
    WORKDIR /
    COPY ./src /app
    COPY ./src/uwsgi.ini /app/uwsgi.ini
    
    WORKDIR /app/
```

> Command line output

```
            => [builder-base 3/5] WORKDIR /opt/pysetup                                                                                                                                       0.0s
     => [builder-base 4/5] COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml ./                                                                                                                     0.0s
     => ERROR [builder-base 5/5] RUN poetry install  # respects                                                                                                                       9.7s
    ------
     > [builder-base 5/5] RUN poetry install  # respects:
    #10 0.950 Creating virtualenv flask-user-module in /opt/pysetup/.venv
    #10 1.954 Installing dependencies from lock file
    #10 2.157
    #10 2.157 Package operations: 11 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
    #10 2.157
    #10 2.158   • Installing markupsafe (2.1.1)
    #10 3.916   • Installing click (8.1.3)
    #10 3.918   • Installing itsdangerous (2.1.2)
    #10 3.921   • Installing jinja2 (3.1.2)
    #10 3.924   • Installing werkzeug (2.2.2)
    #10 5.534   • Installing flask (2.2.2)
    #10 5.534   • Installing mysqlclient (2.1.1)
    #10 5.538   • Installing pymysql (1.0.2)
    #10 9.285
    #10 9.285   CalledProcessError
    #10 9.285
    #10 9.285   Command '['/opt/pysetup/.venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix', '/opt/pysetup/.venv', '--no-deps', '/root/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/af/19/9f/f71f7f0d313981e3dce1608dc021f6f4a338dd61aa21f8e1bbeb8a1deb/mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    #10 9.285
    #10 9.285   at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:526 in run
    #10 9.357        522│             # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
    #10 9.357        523│             raise
    #10 9.357        524│         retcode = process.poll()
    #10 9.358        525│         if check and retcode:
    #10 9.358     →  526│             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
    #10 9.358        527│                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    #10 9.358        528│     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
    #10 9.358        529│
    #10 9.358        530│
    #10 9.358
    #10 9.358 The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:
    #10 9.359
    #10 9.359
    #10 9.359   EnvCommandError
    #10 9.359
    #10 9.360   Command ['/opt/pysetup/.venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix', '/opt/pysetup/.venv', '--no-deps', '/root/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/af/19/9f/f71f7f0d313981e3dce1608dc021f6f4a338dd61aa21f8e1bbeb8a1deb/mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output:
    #10 9.360   Processing /root/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/af/19/9f/f71f7f0d313981e3dce1608dc021f6f4a338dd61aa21f8e1bbeb8a1deb/mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz
    #10 9.360     Installing build dependencies: started
    #10 9.360     Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    #10 9.360     Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    #10 9.360     Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
    #10 9.360     error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    #10 9.360
    #10 9.360     × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    #10 9.360     │ exit code: 1
    #10 9.360     ╰─> [27 lines of output]
    #10 9.360         mysql_config --version
    #10 9.360         /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    #10 9.360         mariadb_config --version
    #10 9.360         /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    #10 9.360         mysql_config --libs
    #10 9.360         /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    #10 9.360         Traceback (most recent call last):
    #10 9.360           File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
    #10 9.360             main()
    #10 9.360           File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
    #10 9.360             json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    #10 9.360           File "/opt/pysetup/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    #10 9.360             return hook(config_settings)
    #10 9.360           File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xebq6tlg/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    #10 9.360             return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    #10 9.360           File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xebq6tlg/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
    #10 9.360             self.run_setup()
    #10 9.360           File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xebq6tlg/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 483, in run_setup
    #10 9.360             super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    #10 9.360           File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xebq6tlg/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
    #10 9.360             exec(code, locals())
    #10 9.360           File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
    #10 9.360           File "/tmp/pip-req-build-xvtg4k3u/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
    #10 9.360             libs = mysql_config("libs")
    #10 9.360           File "/tmp/pip-req-build-xvtg4k3u/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
    #10 9.360             raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    #10 9.360         OSError: mysql_config not found
    #10 9.360         [end of output]
    #10 9.360
    #10 9.360     note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    #10 9.360   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    #10 9.360
    #10 9.360   × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    #10 9.360   │ exit code: 1
    #10 9.360   ╰─> See above for output.
    #10 9.360
    #10 9.360   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    #10 9.360
    #10 9.360
    #10 9.360   at /opt/poetry/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1476 in _run
    #10 9.428       1472│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
    #10 9.428       1473│                     command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env, **kwargs
    #10 9.428       1474│                 )
    #10 9.428       1475│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    #10 9.428     → 1476│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
    #10 9.429       1477│
    #10 9.429       1478│         return decode(output)
    #10 9.429       1479│
    #10 9.429       1480│     def execute(self, bin: str, *args: str, **kwargs: Any) -> int:
    #10 9.429   Failed to install /root/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/af/19/9f/f71f7f0d313981e3dce1608dc021f6f4a338dd61aa21f8e1bbeb8a1deb/mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz
    #10 9.429
    #10 9.429   at /opt/poetry/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/utils/pip.py:51 in pip_install
    #10 9.431        47│
    #10 9.431        48│     try:
    #10 9.431        49│         return environment.run_pip(*args)
    #10 9.431        50│     except EnvCommandError as e:
    #10 9.432     →  51│         raise PoetryException(f"Failed to install {path.as_posix()}") from e
    #10 9.432        52│
    #10 9.432
    ------
    executor failed running [/bin/sh -c poetry install  # respects]: exit code: 1
    ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

> Update

```
(flask-user-module-py3.10) PS D:\Projects\user-module\deploy> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --env-file ./web-variables.env build
mysql uses an image, skipping
Building web
[+] Building 16.3s (10/17)
 => [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.78kB                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim                                                                                                               1.3s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 598B                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => CACHED [python-base 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim@sha256:685b1c2ef40bd3ded77b3abd0965d5c16d19a20469be0ac06a3cf1d33f2e6d41                                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder-base 1/5] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y         curl         build-essential        default-libmysqlclient-dev         0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder-base 2/5] RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python                                                                                            0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder-base 3/5] WORKDIR /opt/pysetup                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder-base 4/5] COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml ./                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => ERROR [builder-base 5/5] RUN poetry install  # respects                                                                                                                      14.8s
#10 3.601   • Installing werkzeug (2.2.2)
#10 5.295   • Installing flask (2.2.2)
#10 5.296   • Installing mysqlclient (2.1.1)
#10 5.297   • Installing pymysql (1.0.2)
#10 10.25   • Installing flask-mysql (1.5.2)
#10 10.25   • Installing flask-mysqldb (1.0.1)
#10 10.25   • Installing flask-paginate (2022.1.8)
#10 14.64
#10 14.64 /opt/pysetup/flask_user_module does not contain any element
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c poetry install  # respects]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems mysql_config is missing in your `web` image. I guess you need to change this line to:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        curl \
        build-essential \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

If one above doesn't work, try to install `python-dev` and `python-MySQLdb`

Comment: Package libmysqlclient-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 However the following packages replace it:
   libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
#5 6.600 E: Package 'libmysqlclient-dev' has no installation candidate
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y         curl         build-essential            libmysqlclient-dev]: exit code: 100
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
@svfat

Comment: @Mohanraj I think it is `default-libmysqlclient-dev` I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: After changing to '''default-libmysqlclient-dev'''
this following error occurs..
#10 10.25   • Installing flask-paginate (2022.1.8)
#10 14.64
#10 14.64 /opt/pysetup/flask_user_module does not contain any element
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c poetry install  # respects]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed

Comment: Please create an UPDATE section in your original question with full error output

Comment: could you look on the update part, i have updated the Question

Comment: Is this one related? https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1227

Comment: no its not related to this issue

Comment: could you  look it

Answer (score 0):

I think it might work if, in your `Dockerfile`, you add the `--no-root` flag to the first `poetry install` command. This tells poetry to skip the final step of installing the package root, which Docker does not have access to at this point.

If this doesn't work, I might have to take a look at your `pyproject.toml` file.